# Dynamic file name with custom outputter

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to process images (create thumbnail images) using u-sql with custom outputter and trying to output files with dynamic file name.

My u-sql code look like this.

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [USQLAssemblies];

@image_out =
SELECT USQLAssemblies.ImageOps.scaleImageTo(ImgData, 480, 480) AS thumbnail_image,
       FileName + "480" AS FileName
FROM dbo.ThumbnailImages;


OUTPUT @image_out
TO @"D:\Test\{FileName}.gif"
USING new USQLAssemblies.ImageOutputter();
```

The script returned an error.

> Error: Data partitioned output is not supported for user-defined outputters.

Does u-sql support custom outputter with dynamic file name? or is it in preview?
Any suggestion for workaround?

Answer (score 1):

To use partitioned output you need to activate this on preview functions.

You can try to add this line to beginning of your code.

```
SET @@FeaturePreviews = "DataPartitionedOutput:on";
```

If not works, you will need to contact usql team to activate it on your account.

Comment: If it still not work with that "Preview:on", please update the U-SQL SDK to latest:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK/1.4.190104

Comment: If you are user of ADLA Tools in VS IDE, please use this release below. We fixed a package metadata issue in the package.   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK/1.4.190114

Comment: PS: if you see errors like below, please "unblock" the downloaded Nuget first: 
 The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.NotSupportedException Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)